# BigQuery python insert with Record (\w client.insert_rows)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, insert, google-bigquery

I am currently trying to insert a row into a BQ dataset.

I want to use the Client.insert_row() function for this 
[documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.insert_rows)

I got everything up and running, for a simple schema without any field of type 'Record'.
However, when I add a field of type 'Record' to my Schema, I dont know how to define this in the insert_row() function

My Schema:
[Schema in BQ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntcI3.png)

My Code:

```
client = bigquery.Client(
    credentials=credentials,
    project=credentials.project_id,
)

dataset_ref = client.dataset('channel_data')

table_ref = dataset_ref.table('test')
table = client.get_table(table_ref)  # API call

rows_to_insert = [{"test1":"a","test2":"b","test3":"c","record":{"1":"d","2":"e"}},]

errors = client.insert_rows_json(table, rows_to_insert)  # API request
assert errors == []
```

I tried many different versions for the row _to_insert:

```
rows_to_insert = [{"test1":"a","test2":"b","test3":"c","record":["d","e"]},]
rows_to_insert = [{"test1":"a","test2":"b","test3":"c","record.1":"d","record.2":"e"}},]
```

none of them seem to work and I can't find any information online how to do this.
Has anyone ever done this before?

It is important that it is inserted as a JSON, since sometimes some of the values are missing.
I know you can just put everything into a list and transfer it like this

```
rows_to_insert = [("a", "b", "c", ["d", "e"])]
```

but that is not an option for me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right way to insert them is as follows:

```
rows_to_insert = [{"test1":"a","test2":"b","test3":"c","record":{"r1":"d","r2":"e"}}]
```

the record field has itself a dictionary as an entry with the specific fields as key/values!

Comment: One observation while using insert_rows_json API. I use this API to insert json rows like this:   `result = bq_client.insert_rows_json(table=bq_table, json_rows=json_rows, skip_invalid_rows=False, ignore_unknown_values=False)
    print(result)` . If there is mismatch between json rows and the bq table schema then, I don't get all the errors back in the same result list. I was expecting list of all errors for json insert. If I run the same statement multiple times, I get different schema error in each API call. any solution for this?